# Selecting a random point on a function.

Tags: calculus, functions, random, arc-length

Say there is a continuous function $f(x)$ which does not have any undefined points in the interval $[a,b[$. I want to randomly select a point $(x,y)$ in that interval on the line formed by that function.

This seems to be no easy task, as simply picking a random value of $x$ and thus getting a point will not give a "fair" chance in every possible case to all of the points in the interval on the actual function. Naturally, this is the case because the derivative can vary in different points in that interval. From that too, the "length" of the line of the function in that interval will also be longer than the interval itself.

The closest thing I can imagine to this would be to literally travel on an imaginary boat across the range of the line defined by the interval up to a randomly selected point on its length. To that extent, we could calculate the [arc length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length) of that interval, pick a random point in that range, and then convert that point to a point on the curve. However, the last process just brings us a whole new problem.

*Just for reference, yes $f(x), [a,b[$ has to be generalized. Any function (which is not piecewise) satisfying the aforementioned conditions is being considered here.*

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your discussion about the arclength is in fact the answer to your question. And indeed parametrizing the curve using the arclength could be a computational problem.

Comment: To clarify, $f$ need not be continuously differentiable (or even differentiable)?

Comment: The "easiest" parameterization is to treat every dimension equally: $\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n \equiv \vec{f}(t) = \left\langle x_i(t)\right\rangle, 1 \leq i \leq n$ (so $n$ different real functions, one for each dimension). Then (Euclidean) distance is just Pythagorean theorem--of course, you could choose whatever metric. Then you can certainly numerically compute that--probably can be done using cubic splines fairly well (but not all curves).